# Cygwin not recognized as Unix compatibility toolchain by Cabal

Tags: haskell, cygwin, cabal

Greetings,

Trying to install a sample [Snap Framework](http://snapframework.com/) project using Cabal while on Windows 7 and in Cygwin.

```
cabal install
```

on my project in cygwin ends with

> Resolving dependencies... 
>   Configuring unix-2.4.1.0... 
>   cabal.exe: The package has a './configure' script. This requires a Unix 
>   compatibility toolchain such as MinGW+MSYS or Cygwin. 
>   cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install: 
>   proj-0.1 depends on unix-2.4.1.0 which failed to install. 
>   unix-2.4.1.0 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
>   ExitFailure 1

Sadly, I get this while inside cygwin.

So far, I've found that [this discussion](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/nDNOvTX9vBvr5VG0IrJf) references a similar problem, but its proposed solution (install MinGW) seems like overkill, given that things should work within cygwin.

I'm fairly new to Haskell, so not really sure what conf files I should play with or what the actual dependencies are. Pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Remember, cabal is a normal Windows application, so if the Cygwin stuff isn't in your path, it isn't going to find it.  Being "inside" Cygwin is a meaningless statement.

Comment: @jrockway: Does this mean I can run "cabal upgrade directory" from a CMD prompt in windows as long as I have cygwin\bin in my path?

Answer (score 4):

You need C:\cygwin and C:\cygwin\bin in your path.  Then you can do this within cmd.

Answer (score 3):

If I were doing it I'd try to install the unix package by hand using the Setup file:

Download the tar archive of unix-2.4.1.0 from Hackage and drop it into cygwin's /usr/local

```
> cd /usr/local
> tar xvfz unix-2.4.1.0.tar.gz
> cd unix-2.4.1.0

> runhaskell Setup.hs configure
> runhaskell Setup.hs build
> runhaskell Setup.hs install
```

If this works you can then go back to using Cabal to install Snap automatically.

Looking at the dependencies for Snap, unix and unix-compat are the only ones I'd expect problems with, most of the others seem to be pure Haskell libraries rather than FFI bindings.

Comment: Thanks! I've moved to developing in ubuntu for now, but I'll come back to windows one of these days and try it out.

Answer (score 2):

Try using http://andlinux.org rather than Cygwin. I find it works better, is easier to install and maintain, and feels more like a linux box integrated with your windows setup. I think it is Debian-based, so if you are used to Ubuntu it should be an easy transition.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you already have Git installed on your Windows, you can just put `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin` to your `PATH`. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Lastest [Haskell platform](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/) from May 2011 and cygwin updated as of today worked like a charm for a simple Snap project for me.

Comment: how did you run cabal? With-in a bash shell? Or just in a CMD window with Cygwin in the path?

Comment: Thank you! (I obviously have no clue how Windows+CygWin+Cabal is supposed to interact.)